# Where can I find the source codes of SoundTrigger HAL for Nexus 6?

Tags: android, hal

I can find SoundTrigger HAL source codes of Nexus 9 in android-5.1.0_r1/device/htc/flounder/audio/soundtrigger.
But I can not find the source codes for Nexus 6.
Is there anyone who can help me?